# HTTPLIB2 Error installing python-twitter on mac osx

Tags: python-twitter

Hello I am trying to install `python-twitter` and one of the dependencies `HTTPLIB2` is giving me a lot of problems. I have searched the internet up and down but maybe I do not know what the right key words are. Here is the problem.

I am installing `python-twitter`. I install the requirements either by `"pip install -r requirements.txt"` or doing them one by one through for example `"pip install httplib2"`. Then I run `"python setup.py install"`. It's happy but then `"python setup.py test"` fails as followed with an error on `import HTTPLIB2`.

```
python setup.py test
running test
running egg_info
writing requirements to python_twitter.egg-info/requires.txt
writing python_twitter.egg-info/PKG-INFO
writing top-level names to python_twitter.egg-info/top_level.txt
writing dependency_links to python_twitter.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
reading manifest file 'python_twitter.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
no previously-included directories found matching '.DS_Store'
writing manifest file 'python_twitter.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
running build_ext
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "setup.py", line 73, in <module>
    Main()
  File "setup.py", line 66, in Main
    setuptools.setup(**METADATA)
  File
```

....

```
<deleted these parts to save space>
    module = __import__('.'.join(parts_copy))
  File "/Users/ME/Downloads/python-twitter-1.0/twitter_test.py", line 30, in <module>
    import twitter
  File "/Users/ME/Downloads/python-twitter-1.0/twitter.py", line 65, in <module>
    import oauth2 as oauth
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/oauth2/__init__.py", line 32, in <module>
    import httplib2
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/httplib2/__init__.py", line 347
    print('%s:' % h, end=' ', file=self._fp)
                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

But I thought the print error was an incompatibility between python 2 and 3. Why am I getting this while I clearly have python 2.7 (I checked and uninstalled and reinstalled HTTPLIB2).
Thanks much for your help

Comment: I just needed to change HTTPLIB2 version in my requirements.txt to httplib2==0.7.7  pip installs the latest version which is apparently not compatible with python 2.7. This question needs to be closed. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

i had a same issue. It seems to be python2.7 and 3.x version conflict issue and resolved by

```
python2.7 -m pip install -t lib/ -r requirements.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

Just in case, this happens when you install httplib2 with a python3 version of pip and then execute it with python2.

This happens for example when creating manually an environment with:

```
pip install -t lib/ -r requirements
```

As it happens when creating an AppEngine standard environment vendor folder.

This happens because contrary to most of the libraries, httplib2 has completely different versions for python2 and python3.